# Contrary to Firefox, "onDragStart" is called by Chromium when a component is newly mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, chromium, react-dnd

When a component is newly mounted, `onDragStart` is called by Chrome (neither `onMouseDown` nor `onPointerDown` are called) while in Firefox this does not happen (nothing is called).

This causes libraries like "React DnD" to not work as expected.

See the following codesandbox to reproduce, when the component is just mounted (click and instantly dragged) see how the console prints the message produced in `OnDragStart`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-sea-p1qr15

Which (Firefox / Chromium) handles the standard behavior (is there any in general?)? It seems to me that an `onDragStart` should not be called without its respective `onMouseDown`, so this would be a bug in Chrome?

Thanks in advance.